# How to add additional fields in React Query Builder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, query-builder

I am trying to achieve the following: When a user enters a specific value, then additional fields are displayed, there the user can enter the values, also the values from this fields should be displayed when exporting the query to json.

I am passing this custom editor to `controlElements={{ valueEditor: CustomValueEditor }}` on `<QueryBuilder />` and it adds these fields when the required values are specified. But I cannot get X, Y and Z when exporting.

```
const CustomValueEditor = (props: ValueEditorProps) => {
    switch (props.value) {
        case "3d":
            return (
                <div className='demo-space-x'>
                    <ValueEditor {...props} />
                    <input placeholder='X' />
                    <input placeholder='Y' />
                    <input placeholder='Z' />
                </div>
            )
        case "2d":
            return (
                <div className='demo-space-x'>
                    <ValueEditor {...props} />
                    <input placeholder='X' />
                    <input placeholder='Y' />
                </div>
            )

        default:
            return <ValueEditor {...props} />
    }
}
```

Here is how I specify a field that takes the value `2d` or `3d`.

```
{
  name: 'system',
  label: 'system',
  inputType: 'string',
  operators: [equal, notEqual, less, lessOrEqual, greater, greaterOrEqual],
}
```

I know that in the JQuery JavaScript version there is a `ValueGetter` and a `ValueSetter`, which greatly simplifies this task. How can I achieve this result in React Query Builder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of `react-querybuilder` here. What I usually recommend in this situation is to store all values that you want to track on the `value` property itself. This can take the form of an array, object, comma-separated string, whatever works best for your use case.

If you do it this way, you'll need to make sure of two things:

1. The custom value editor component needs to handle the complex `value` property, so for example if your rule object looks like this...

```json
{
  "field": "system",
  "operator": "=",
  "value": {
    "actualValue": "the actual value",
    "x": "x value",
    "y": "y value",
    "z": "z value"
  }
}
```

...then `props.value` passed to your custom value editor will be an object with `actualValue`, `x`, `y`, and `z` properties. Your value editor code should break them out and apply the properties to the appropriate controls.

2. You need to persist the entire object when updating the "value". When you call `props.handleOnChange` from your custom value editor, don't just call it with the `value` from the main control, call it with the full `props.value` object, with only the `actualValue` property updated (or `x` or `y` or whatever).

There are other ways to accomplish this, and these kinds of scenarios will get easier to manage in version 7 (coming soon...I hope!).

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your work, the library is really great and I'll be waiting for updates. Thanks for the advice, I will try to implement it.